# combining two tkinter files together to make a single program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two tkinter files, one with a welcome screen and the other with the selection menu, I have created two separate tkinter files and combine them to make it a single program where the welcome screen dissolves after 10 seconds and the selection menu appears.

my code:

1. welcome screen:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

from tkinter.ttk import *


#icon

root = Tk()

root.title("-----")

root.geometry("425x508")

root.iconbitmap('left this on purpose')



#welcome screen

welcome = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("left this on purpose"))

lbl = Label(image=welcome)

lbl.pack()

root.after(10000, lambda: root.destroy())
```

2. selection menu screen:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

from tkinter.ttk import *

#icon

root = Tk()

root.title("selection")

root.geometry("325x396")

root.iconbitmap("left this on purpose")

 
select = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("left this on purpose"))

lbl2 = Label(image=select)

lbl2.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add a way to display the welcome screen, however, if that's what you wanted:

main.py -

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

from tkinter.ttk import *

from selectionmenu import app


#icon

root = Tk()

root.title("-----")

root.geometry("425x508")


# stuff you want to do
root.after(10000, app)
```

selectionmenu.py -

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

from tkinter.ttk import *

# icon

def app():
    root = Tk()

    root.title("selection")

    root.geometry("325x396")

    root.mainloop()
```

I don't think this is the way to proceed by having two instances of Tk(), but using the Toplevel widget doesn't provide a way to delete the root window and using the toplevel.

Comment: `root.after(10000, app())` will execute `app()` immediately, not after 10 seconds.  It should be `root.after(10000, app)`.